# import specific data from a json feed

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

folks I need your help.
I have this JSON structure and I would like to import just a few items to google spreadsheets such as ID, DESCRICAO e PRECO, however I am not able to capture only these items with my code.

```
{
"retorno": {
"produtos": [
{
"produto": {
"id": "11822756183",
"codigo": "",
"descricao": "PLUG BORNE - BNC MACHO 50 OHMS COM BORNE - PARAFUSO PCT/10 - 062-9961 - SANTANA",
"tipo": "P",
"situacao": "Ativo",
"unidade": "D1",
"preco": "16.4700000000",
"precoCusto": "16.4700000000",
"descricaoCurta": null,
"descricaoComplementar": null,
"dataInclusao": "2021-03-25",
"dataAlteracao": "2021-03-25",
"imageThumbnail": null,
"urlVideo": "",
"nomeFornecedor": "SIMPLES SOLUTIONS COME DE EQUIP ELETRONICOS LTDA",
"codigoFabricante": "31469",
"marca": "",
"class_fiscal": "8536.69.90",
"cest": "",
"origem": "2",
"idGrupoProduto": "0",
"linkExterno": null,
"observacoes": "",
"grupoProduto": null,
"garantia": "0",
"descricaoFornecedor": "PLUG BORNE - BNC MACHO 50 OHMS COM BORNE - PARAFUSO PCT/10 - 062-9961 - SANTANA",
"idFabricante": "11822750692",
"categoria": {
"id": "980535",
"descricao": "Categoria padrão"
},
"pesoLiq": "0.00000",
"pesoBruto": "0.00000",
"estoqueMinimo": null,
"estoqueMaximo": null,
"gtin": "",
"gtinEmbalagem": "",
"larguraProduto": null,
"alturaProduto": null,
"profundidadeProduto": null,
"unidadeMedida": "Centímetros",
"itensPorCaixa": 0,
"volumes": 0,
"localizacao": "",
"crossdocking": "",
"condicao": "Novo",
"freteGratis": "N",
"producao": "T",
"dataValidade": null,
"spedTipoItem": "",
"estoqueAtual": 0,
"depositos": [
{
"deposito": {
"id": "146989099",
"nome": "Geral",
"saldo": 0,
"desconsiderar": "N",
"saldoVirtual": 0
}
}
]
}
},
```

Code I'm trying to use

```
function callBling() {
  // Call the Bling API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("apikey");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
   // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  Logger.log(data);
  Logger.log(data["produtos"]);
  Logger.log(data["produtos"]["produto"]);
  Logger.log(data["produtos"]["produto"]["0"]["id"]);
  Logger.log(data["produtos"]["produto"][0]["descricao"]);
  Logger.log(data["produtos"]["produto"][0]["preco"]);
}
```

but with this code you are not importing the data correctly into the logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of `id, descricao, preco` from the JSON data in your question.
- You want to put the retrieved values to the Spreadsheet.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, for example, at `Logger.log(data["produtos"]["produto"]["0"]["id"])`, `data["produtos"]` is `null`. From your sample value, it's `data["retorno"]["produtos"]`. And, `["0"]` is the key. When you want to use `0` as the index of array, please use `[0]`. In your sample value, the array is `data["retorno"]["produtos"]`. So when you want to retrieve the value of `id` in the 1st element of `data["retorno"]["produtos"]`, please use `data["retorno"]["produtos"][0]["produto"]["id"]`.
- In order to put the retrieved values to Google Spreadsheet, it is required to create the values as the 2 dimensional array.

When above points are reflected to the script, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```
function callBling() {
  // Call the Bling API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("apikey");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
   // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  // I added below script.
  var values = data.retorno.produtos.map(({produto: {id, descricao, preco}}) => [id, descricao, preco]);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this modified script is run, the values are put to "Sheet1" in the active Spreadsheet.
- In this modified script, it supposes that the value of `data` of `var data = JSON.parse(json)` is the sample value in your question. When the strudture of actual data is different from your sampe values, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

#### Note:

- In order to check the value of `values` in above script, you can also test the following script using your sample values.

  ```js
      var data = {
        "retorno": {
          "produtos": [
            {
              "produto": {
                "id": "11822756183",
                "codigo": "",
                "descricao": "PLUG BORNE - BNC MACHO 50 OHMS COM BORNE - PARAFUSO PCT/10 - 062-9961 - SANTANA",
                "tipo": "P",
                "situacao": "Ativo",
                "unidade": "D1",
                "preco": "16.4700000000",
                "precoCusto": "16.4700000000",
                "descricaoCurta": null,
                "descricaoComplementar": null,
                "dataInclusao": "2021-03-25",
                "dataAlteracao": "2021-03-25",
                "imageThumbnail": null,
                "urlVideo": "",
                "nomeFornecedor": "SIMPLES SOLUTIONS COME DE EQUIP ELETRONICOS LTDA",
                "codigoFabricante": "31469",
                "marca": "",
                "class_fiscal": "8536.69.90",
                "cest": "",
                "origem": "2",
                "idGrupoProduto": "0",
                "linkExterno": null,
                "observacoes": "",
                "grupoProduto": null,
                "garantia": "0",
                "descricaoFornecedor": "PLUG BORNE - BNC MACHO 50 OHMS COM BORNE - PARAFUSO PCT/10 - 062-9961 - SANTANA",
                "idFabricante": "11822750692",
                "categoria": {
                  "id": "980535",
                  "descricao": "Categoria padrão"
                },
                "pesoLiq": "0.00000",
                "pesoBruto": "0.00000",
                "estoqueMinimo": null,
                "estoqueMaximo": null,
                "gtin": "",
                "gtinEmbalagem": "",
                "larguraProduto": null,
                "alturaProduto": null,
                "profundidadeProduto": null,
                "unidadeMedida": "Centímetros",
                "itensPorCaixa": 0,
                "volumes": 0,
                "localizacao": "",
                "crossdocking": "",
                "condicao": "Novo",
                "freteGratis": "N",
                "producao": "T",
                "dataValidade": null,
                "spedTipoItem": "",
                "estoqueAtual": 0,
                "depositos": [
                  {
                    "deposito": {
                      "id": "146989099",
                      "nome": "Geral",
                      "saldo": 0,
                      "desconsiderar": "N",
                      "saldoVirtual": 0
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }]
        }
      };

      var values = data.retorno.produtos.map(({produto: {id, descricao, preco}}) => [id, descricao, preco]);
      console.log(values);
  ```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @Welison Beletatte Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: I would like to know if you could help me with one more question regarding this code, it would be possible to format the value of the "price" field, as it is like "16.4700000000" and I would like it to be just 2 after the point. I'm not getting through with the code I'm developing

Comment: @Welison Beletatte About your new question, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue and I cannot understand about `the code I'm developing`, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: hello friend, I created a new question with my doubt, if you can help me thank you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67496993/format-json-data-import-in-google-sheets

Comment: @Welison Beletatte Thank you for your response. Now, when I saw your new question, I noticed that an answer has already been commented. I think that it will resolve your issue.