# format JSON data import in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

with the help of member / friend @Tanaike we were able to develop a code to import the data from a JSON list, but the data in the "price" field is imported as follows '16 .4700000000 'and I would like to import only the first 2 digits after the' . ' getting "16.47".

could you help me on this mission?

this is the current code I am using:

````
  // Call the Bling API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/produtos/json&apikey=APIKEY?imagem=S&estoque=S");
  //Logger.log(response.getContentText());
   // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  // Aquisição de dados.
  var values = data.retorno.produtos.map(({produto: {codigo, gtin, descricao, preco, situacao}}) => [codigo, gtin, descricao, preco, situacao]);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("produtos");
  sheet.getRange(/*sheet.getLastRow() + */ 2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values); ```
````

Comment: try this `var values = data.retorno.produtos.map(({produto: {codigo, gtin, descricao, preco, situacao}}) => [codigo, gtin, descricao, Number(preco).toFixed(2), situacao])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from one of my projects where I set the number format as well as borders and background.

```
  sheet.getRange(summaryAnnRetsFirstRow, 1, summaryAnnRetsLen, 4).setValues(summaryAnnRets);
  sheet.getRange(summaryAnnRetsFirstRow,2, summaryAnnRetsLen, 2).setNumberFormat("$#,##0;$(#,##0)");
  sheet.getRange(summaryAnnRetsFirstRow,4, summaryAnnRetsLen, 1).setNumberFormat("0.00%");
  sheet.getRange(summaryAnnRetsFirstRow,1, summaryAnnRetsLen, sheet.getLastColumn()).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, 'black', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_LIGHT);
  sheet.getRange(summaryAnnRetsFirstRow,1, summaryAnnRetsLen, sheet.getLastColumn()).setBackground("#bdd4f9");
```